# How can I make a background continuous?

Tags: html, css, background-image

As you can see, in the title block, only the upper half has background, I want the whole title block to have the same background. Of course, I can set background for the title block itself, but this way the background won't look continuous, as you can see in the fiddle.

Is there a way to achieve this with pure css?

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 30%;
  background: url('https://cchc-herald.org/images/discuss_cavatar/titleSampleBG.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 8px 24px;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  left: 10%
}

body {
  background-color: #eee
}

.title.b {
  background: url('https://cchc-herald.org/images/discuss_cavatar/titleSampleBG.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: contain
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title"> Title Title </div>
</div>

<div class="header" style="margin-top:60px">
  <div class="title b">
    Title Title
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s7pkr2w8/1/

Comment: The background _is_ full size. It's just that you've translated your child element outside the header. You need to restructure to fix that. We can't really offer suggestions not knowing what your overall goals are.

Comment: @isherwood the goal is to have the background continue to the translated child. To cover the missing part outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea using clipping and masking

```css
.header {
  padding-top: 30%;
  position: relative; /* relative here !! **/
  display:flex;
  z-index:0;
}
.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin:auto auto 0 10%; /* position the element using flexbox instead of absolute */
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff 0 0); /* clip the pseudo element to only the title shape*/
}
/* extra div needed for the white border*/
.title > div {
  padding: 8px 24px;
  border:4px solid #fff;
  position:relative;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
/**/
/* two pseudo element relative to the container having the same background
   to have the continuous effect
*/
.title::before,
.header::before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background: url('https://cchc-herald.org/images/discuss_cavatar/titleSampleBG.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%/cover;
}

.header::before {
  clip-path:inset(0 0 20px 0); /* cut 20px from the bottom to be around the middle of the title */
}

body{
  background-color:#eee
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title">
    <div>Title Title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Very rich answer. A lot of information to take in. Is `mask` only supported by webkit based browsers?

Comment: @shenkwen no, it also works in Firefox too even with the prefixes. You can add the non prefix version if you want but not needed actually

Answer (score -1):

you can try to set the background on a parent element or just event to the whole body:

```
 body{
   background:url('https://cchc-herald.org/images/discuss_cavatar/titleSampleBG.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
   background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: That's not the problem here. You should copy the snippet to your answer so you can demonstrate a working solution.